# Run-Time Check Failure #0 - (The value of ESP was not properly saved) - when calling function as stored in a structure

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, function

I've checked the other solutions here and they don't seem to apply.
I have function prototypes declared as:

```
typedef FTC_STATUS(CALLBACK *SPI_SetGPIOsFuncPtr)(FTC_HANDLE ftHandle);
```

These are used in my structure like this:

```
struct FTDIFuncs
{
SPI_SetGPIOsFuncPtr SPI_SetGPIOs;
    plus other functions
}
```

the function in question is defined like this:

```
FTC_STATUS WINAPI SPI_SetGPIOs(FTC_HANDLE ftHandle);
```

The function is assigned to the structure like this:

```
ftdiFuncs.SPI_SetGPIOs = reinterpret_cast<SPI_SetGPIOsFuncPtr>(SPI_GetGPIOs);
```

The function is called like this:

```
status = ftdiFuncs->SPI_SetGPIOs(ftcHandle)
```

However on return I get the run time error as described above.
Obvious checks:
1. the function ptr typedef and the function itself have the same args
2. Both `CALLBACK` and `WINAPI` are defined to be `__stdcall`. In any case I changed both the typedef and the function prototype to both be `WINAPI` and I got the same error.
3. calling other functions in `ftdiFuncs` works as expected.
It's probably worth pointing out that all of the above `ftdi` funcs and function ptrs are compiled into a library which the main project links in.

Comment: You are using `reinterpret_cast`. You shouldn't need that if the signatures match. It may be masking the true error. What error do you get if you take it out?

Comment: thanks ! that sorted the problem. wait for it .... I had a typo and was converting the wrong function over in the cast !! duh!

Answer (score 0):

Duh! I was converting GetGPIOs to SetGPIOs !!!
Look carefully:
SPI_SetGPIOs = reinterpret_cast(SPI_GetGPIOs)